# Como meto autoplay e paro um video quando abro e fecho uma modal

Tags: modal, youtube

boa tarde, eu criei uma modal e dentro dessa modal meti um video de youtube só que pretenderia que ele, assim que abrisse a modal, desse em autoplay e parasse quando fechasse a modal. não estou conseguindo fazer isso com video de youtube ou vimeo... será que alguem me pode dar uma ajuda?

muito obrigado.

o meu codigo é este

HTML

```
<a href="#MODAL1" class="image-link">video</a>


<div id="MODAL1" class="overlayy2">
    <div class="MODAL1">
        <br>
        <a class="close icon-link" href="#">X</a>
        <div class="content2">
        <br>
        <iframe width="550" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ArxPy04p_4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 332.8px; height: 242.036px;" data-meta=" class="" data-scale="32"></iframe>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlayy2 {
  position: fixed;
   z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  

}
.overlayy2:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.Entrevista1 {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background:black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}



.Entrevista1 h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
            line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #befee1;
    text-align: justify;


}
.Entrevista1 .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #befee1;
}
.Entrevista1 .close:hover {
  color: red;
}
.Entrevista1 .content2 {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

  .Entrevista1{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  
  .Entrevista1 h1 {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

No HTML5 tem uma TAG chamada  `<video> </video>` nesta tag você consegue adicionar atributos de autoplay e de controles quando  passar o mouse em cima do video, por exemplo:

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="nomedovideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use um Iframe apontando para o vídeo no Modal, no botão de abrir você atribui uma função para recarregar este IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Para dar um autoplay no vídeo do Youtube, você pode utilizar do *queryparam* `autoplay`, enviando o valor `1`:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ArxPy04p_4?autoplay=1

Veja que o vídeo é aberto e já é dado o play de forma automática.

---

Para fechar a modal e com isso o vídeo ser pausado, uma opção é limpar o `src` do `iframe`, algo assim:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("MeuIframeDoYouTube");
ifram.src = "";
```

Porém com isso, ao clicar no modal novamente, não existirá `src`, e o modal será exibido vazio, então quando o modal ser exibido, você precisará fazer um código semelhante, só que colocando novamente o `src` no `iframe`:

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("MeuIframeDoYouTube");
ifram.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ArxPy04p_4?autoplay=1";
```

---

Juntando essas ideias, você terá um código mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```js
function stopVideo() {
    getIFrame().src = "";
}

function startVideo() {
    getIFrame().src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0ArxPy04p_4?autoplay=1";
}

function getIFrame() {
    return document.getElementById("youtube");
}
```

```css
.overlayy2 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlayy2:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.Entrevista1 {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background:black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.Entrevista1 h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #befee1;
  text-align: justify;
}

.Entrevista1 .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #befee1;
}

.Entrevista1 .close:hover {
  color: red;
}

.Entrevista1 .content2 {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

  .Entrevista1{
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  .Entrevista1 h1 {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#MODAL1" class="image-link" onclick="startVideo()">video</a>

<div id="MODAL1" class="overlayy2">
    <div class="MODAL1">
        <br>
        <a onclick="stopVideo()" class="close icon-link" href="#">X</a>
        <div class="content2">
          <br>
          <iframe id="youtube" width="550" height="400" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" style="width: 332.8px; height: 242.036px;" data-scale="32"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Obs.:** O vídeo pode não aparecer no Sopt, então pode testar esse mesmo código [aqui](https://repl.it/@Dadinel/PunctualFocusedBrowsers).

Comment: parece optimo! só que aqui nao consigo meter o  onclick="startVideo()"..... ele so me deixa por <a href="#MODAL1" class="image-link" ...... nao deve dar usando apenas com o href?